# Search Results segue to other View controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchresultscontroller

I am implementing search controller programatically on navigation bar it is working fine and showing result, if I can select the tableview cell(did select method) segue is working fine . when I select the searched result it is not segue to next view controller. It is showing same view controller and tableview is reloading with data. I have show once click search result segue to next view controller

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBDfr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1msxw.png)

```
var modeldata = [ModelData]()
var FilerData = [ModelData]() 


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchcontroller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.searchcontroller.delegate = self
        self.searchcontroller.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchcontroller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchcontroller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchcontroller.searchBar
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return modeldata.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        let values = modeldata[row] as ModelData

        cell.NameLabel.text = values.name 
return cell
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        let searchToSearch = searchController.searchBar.text
        if(searchToSearch == "")
        {
            modeldata = self.FilerData
        }
        else{
            modeldata.removeAll()
            let itemsarray = self.FilerData
            var ListArray = [String]()
            for ListItems in itemsarray {
                ListArray.append(ListItems.name!)
                if(ListItems.name?.range(of: searchToSearch!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil)
                {
                    self.modeldata.append(ListItems)

                }
            }
        }
        self.TableView.reloadData()
      }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "next", sender:indexPath.row )

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let selectrow = sender as? Int
        let name = modeldata[selectrow!].name
        let nextview = segue.destination as? WekiViewController
        nextview?.namestring = name!
    }
```

Comment: If you are implementing transition "programatically", why do you use segue? you could just push WekiViewController directly from func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath).

Comment: @Andrey thanks for replay  when I click the table view cell it is working but when I click search result it not navigating next view controller